# Select option validation using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

/**
Html Code **/

```
<form id="regForm" action="/action_page.php">
  <center>
  <h1>Apply For Job</h1></center><hr style="width: 2in;">
  <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
  <div class="tab "><strong>Personal Details:</strong>
<center>
    <p><input  placeholder="Full Name " oninput="this.className = ''" name="fname"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Higest Education" oninput="this.className = ''" name="sname"></p>
    <p><input  placeholder="Your Age " type="number" oninput="this.className = ''" name="age"></p>
    <div>
      <select id="myselect" style="width:100%;">
      <option selected disabled >Select Gender</option>
      <option value='Male'>Male</option>
      <option value='Female'>Female</option>
      <option value='Others'>Others</option>
    </select>
    
    </div>
<br>
  </div>
</center>
  <div class="tab"><strong>Contact Informations :</strong>
    <p><input placeholder="E-mail" oninput="this.className = ''" name="email" type="email"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Phone Number" oninput="this.className = ''" name="phone" type="tel"></p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

// This function deals with validation of the form fields

```
function validateForm() {
  
  var x, y, i, valid = true;<br />
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");<br />
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");<br />
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {<br />
    // If a field is empty...<br />
    if (y[i].value == "") {<br />
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:<br />
      y[i].className += " invalid";<br />
      // and set the current valid status to false<br />
      valid = false;<br />
    }
  }
```

/** How I validate my select box too? **/
How I make my select box required in this form ?
official form Code https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_form_steps

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_form_steps  I need to add some select option in this form with required

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on what you are trying todo.

But i am going to take a shot in the dark and try to help and answer your question.

```js
var currentTab = 0;
showTab(currentTab);

function showTab(n) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }

  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      valid = false;
    }
  }

  if (0 == document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].selectedIndex) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].className += " invalid";
    return false;
  }

  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid;
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  x[n].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#regForm {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 100px auto;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 70%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

#myselect {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

#myselect.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

.tab {
  display: none;
}

button {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#prevBtn {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
}

.step {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.step.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.step.finish {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
  <form id="regForm" action="/action_page.php">
    <h1>Apply For Job:</h1>
    <div class="tab">Personal Details:
      <p><input placeholder="Full Name" oninput="this.className = ''" name="fullname"></p>
      <p><input placeholder="Higest Education" oninput="this.className = ''" name="education"></p>
      <p><input placeholder="Your Age" oninput="this.className = ''" name="age"></p>
      <p>
        <select id="myselect" style="width: 100%;">
          <option selected disabled>Select Gender</option>
          <option value="Male" name="Male">Male</option>
          <option value="Female" name="Female">Female</option>
          <option value="Others" name="Others">Others</option>
        </select>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="tab">Contact Informations:
      <p><input placeholder="Email" oninput="this.className = ''" name="email"></p>
      <p><input placeholder="Phone Number" oninput="this.className = ''" name="phone"></p>
    </div>

    <div style="overflow: auto;">
      <div style="float: right;">
        <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
        <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
      <span class="step"></span>
      <span class="step"></span>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy !!

Comment: this is exectly what I want !!

Comment: bro but i need one more help . If I put  another select option on very next step where we have submit button so it's doesn't works . Please help me.